# Did "zwo" exist before invention of radio?

Tags: etymology, history

Was "zwo" often or ever used before radio, or was it developed as a result of radio? Or has it just always been used around crowds and loud noises? And have other numbers ever had similar morphological changes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has nothing to do with radio.

*[Zwo](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zwo)* is the female version (from Middle and Old High German zwō, zwā) for the numeral Zwei:

> Zwo Frauen

whereas *[zween](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zween)* is the male version (from Middle and Old High German zwēne)

> zween Männer

Nowadays it isn't any longer in this use. At least *zween* is marked as archaic.

*Zwo* is used colloquial and when you want to differentiate acoustically from *Drei*.

> Eins, Zwo, Drei

instead of

> Eins, Zwei, Drei

Comment: Bzgl. anderen Zahlen: Eens, Zwee, Dree, ... aber ich glaub das ist südländischer Dialekt. Vllt kann dazu jmd anderes was sagen?

Comment: Sehr hilfreich und von anderen beliebt! :-) Danke!

Answer (score 7):

In der zwoten Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts hatte zwo [zwo Höhepunkte lt. Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zwo&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3), also weit vor der Erfindung des Radios [1923 etwa startete der Rundfunk im dt. Reich lt. Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio) :

[image: Google ngram about zwo]

---

In the second half of the 18th century, "zwo" had its all time high, according to google ngram, and this was long before the invention of the radio [around 1923 the Rundfunk im dt. Reich started, according to the German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio).

Comment: Sehr umfangreiche Auskünfte! Danke!